# access view in hooks in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load view for pre controller  hook, but it is giving following error :

**Call to a member function view() on null**

I want to display message on screen for database connectivity from pre controller hook.

Hook controller function code is as follows:

```
public function check_db_connection() {
   $CI = & get_instance();
   $CI->load->view('common/footer');  }
```

Comment: you can refer this link for reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892941/does-codeigniter-have-to-load-view-in-the-final-step

Comment: No, this is different thing. I got error while loading view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the point where the pre-controller hook is called there isn't an instance of a controller that `get_instance()` can return, so it returns NULL. The executing code then effectively becomes

```
NULL->load->view('common/footer');
```

Which of course is nonsense.

"pre-controller" means no controller exists yet and `get_instance()` returns the location of an existing controller.

You might try hooking to the 'post_controller_constructor' instead.