# Perform large operations in PHP without running out of memory?

Tags: php

I'm generating about 700 PDFs with dompdf and saving them to the disk. Each one involves a database query to fetch the information for the PDF. When I run it I get about 2 minutes in and then it runs out of memory.

1. Why am I running out of memory? Shouldn't each PDF generation consume x memory, then release it when finished?
2. What's good practice in PHP for doing large operations like this to avoid strangling your server?

Some more info:

- It generates many PDFs before running out of memory (some 100s)
- The PDF it fails on is not abnormally large or special in any way. They're all between 4KB and ~500KB
- Watching the memory usage as it processes it just slowly climbs in fits and starts until it runs out.

I can't get the wysiwyg to code-format properly, so here's a pastie for the snippets in question: http://pastie.org/3800751

Comment: Is it running out of memory after processing X number of PDFs, or before it finishes processing any?

Comment: Can you create the same PDF 700 times? Maybe it's just one too large PDF reaching the max. memory limit from the php.ini?

Comment: Seconded. We need much more than this to diagnose the problem. What happens if you just generate one PDF? Can you post pseudocode of your algorithm, or even better a minimal example of the problem?

Comment: Try to look into some kind of task queuing: [Run PHP Task Asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously)

Comment: Edited with more info. I wasn't sure what to include before.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably that you running your code asynchronously. Try running it synchronously, it might take a really long time but it will work. Also, make sure to dispose of your objects at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

- Increase memory limit [`ini_set`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)
- Use a cron job, or generally try and run each pdf generation
  asynchronously with a queue.
- Batch (split) processing into a number which
  can be processed within one page load / Redirect after each batch to
  same page using [`header`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) / Keeping track of where you are on each script load with [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) / Beware of redirect limits on browsers

Comment: My intention is to run it on a cron job. How do I run it in batches with a single cron execution? I've had no trouble with the redirect method you mention, but I'm not sure that works in a cron type setup?

Comment: You can chain together multiple executions in a single crontab command so they run sequentially I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In general, large operations like this should be forked into child processes that each handle generating a single PDF. This should avoid the out of memory situation in case your PDF or DB libraries leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `memory_limit` at `php.ini`

Comment: While this may work, it's not diagnosing or fixing the problem.