# How to gracefully tell client the transmission is finished so the browser will display the page immediately?

Tags: php, connection, flush, ob-start

Greeting guys,

I'm working on my php framework. It has a response manager to wrapper php's header, cookie, and buffer functions. I use this to send result page to user.

However, even the page header and contents already be sent by using ob_start -> ob_end_flush -> flush, the browser still hanging and wait for script to complete.

It cause problems when i want to do some slow job like update current user's session or just send a mail or upload something. User will have to wait until everything done, even they already have the whole page including header.

***What I want to know is, how to make browser know the page is completely loaded, so it can display the page right now?***

Thank you!

////////////////////////////  Abandoned Solutions  ////////////////////////////

**Abandoned Solution 1**

In the past, i usually use the combination of ob_start -> ob_end_flush -> ob_flush -> flush to *fix* this problem, it seems will like this:

```
function send($content) {
    ob_start();

    echo $content;

    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    return true;
}
```

**But** the ob_flush will throw a E_NOTICE says it have "No buffer to flush". I don't want to fix this by just mute this E_NOTICE (*and in fact, in my framework, there is no way to mute any error*). So this is not the way to solve this problem.

**Abandoned Solution 2**

I also try to close connection after content sent, code will like this:

```
function send($content) {
    ob_start();

    header('Connection: close');

    echo $content;

    ob_end_flush();

    flush();

    return true;
}
```

It can solve the problem with out any error, but it bring another problem: Seems client's connection will be close after page received, and when they want to open another page, they have to reconnect. This will generate extra load on network.

**Abandoned Solution 3**

Yeah, some people suggested me to use fastcgi, and use fastcgi_finish_request(); But i want to make my code more compatible between environments, so it actually not a option.

Comment: Why would the browser hang? Once the PHP is done output is sent and connection is closed. Try a `die;` after the flush and see if anything changes. Does your PHP script terminate properly?

Comment: @CodeAngry: Sorry, but i don't want to use die, it will make my question pointless. I want to make script continue run after page sent.

Answer (score 0):

On **IIS** you cannot break the connection before the `fastcgi` finishes. You need to use [`fascgi_finish_request()^`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236040/example-of-how-to-use-fastcgi-finish-request) to manually force the finish of the current `CGI`.

On **Apache** you can use the [`Content-Length: 0` **redirect trick**^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504753/can-i-cause-a-redirect-to-occur-before-my-php-script-finishes) which works great but does not work on IIS *(at least not in my experience)*.

**PS**: And make sure you do the `ignore_user_abort(true)` and extend the runtime limit `set_time_limit(0)`*(infinte)* before any of these to prevent PHP from closing when connection is closed by client.

**PPS**: Tasks run after page is sent should go into **cronjobs**. It's the cleaner way to do things.