# use php script to run schedule job

Tags: php, email, cron

I have followed the solution in [How to cause a redirect to occur before php script finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504753/how-to-cause-a-redirect-to-occur-before-php-script-finishes) to make a page will follow schedule to sent email to prevent exceed sending limit of Gmail. The loop works and it can stop after a specific number of emails sent. but the link cannot be redirected until all the code loaded. And is it ok if the code will run for around 6 days?

```
<?php   
//Redirect to messageToUser.php
header("Location: show_message.php");
//Erase the output buffer
ob_end_clean();
//Tell the browser that the connection's closed
header("Connection: close");

//Ignore the user's abort (which we caused with the redirect).
ignore_user_abort(true);

//Extend time limit to 30 minutes
set_time_limit(0);
//Extend memory limit to 10MB
ini_set("memory_limit","10M");
//Start output buffering again
ob_start();

//Tell the browser we're serious... there's really
//nothing else to receive from this page.
header("Content-Length: 0");

//Send the output buffer and turn output buffering off.
ob_end_flush();
//Yes... flush again.
flush();

//Close the session.
session_write_close();

/*---function start---*/

file_put_contents("gate.cfg","Y");
include 'header.php';
$foreword = $footer = "";
$send = $_SESSION['send_template']; //get newsletter information
$news_id = $send['news_id'];
if ($conn){     
    $sql = "select * from newsCat as n1, newsletter as n2 left outer join schedule as s on n2.news_id = s.news_id where n1.news_id = n2.news_id and n2.news_id = $news_id"; //check newsletter stage -- P:processing / F: finish / Null: not sent
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) { //get newsletter information
        $array =  mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $subject = $array['title'];
        $parent_id = $array['cat_id'];
        $filename = "filemanager/file/newsletter/".$array['locat'].".txt";

        $sql = "select c.cat_id,name from category as c, parent as p where p.cat_id = c.cat_id and parent_id=$parent_id"; //get category name
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) { 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) { 
                $category[$row['cat_id']] = $row['name'];
            }

        }       
        //get newsletter information
        $file_id = substr($array['locat'],4,10);    
        $fp = fopen ($filename,"r"); //get newsletter content
        $contents = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
        $content = explode("<!--!@#$%^&*end-->", $contents);
        for ($i=0;$i<count($content);$i++){
            $content[$i] = explode("<!--!@#$%^&*-->", $content[$i]);
            if ($i ==0 || $i == count($content)-1){
                $code[$content[$i][0]] = $content[$i][1];
            }else if ($content[$i][1] !=''){
                $code[$content[$i][0]] = "<h3 style='text-align:center;'>".$category[$content[$i][0]]."</h3>".$content[$i][1];
                $full_content .= $code[$content[$i][0]];
            }

        }
        if ($code['for']!=''){
            $foreword = "<p>$code[for]</p>";
        }
        if ($code['fot']!=''){
            $footer = "<div style='font-size: 10px;border-top: 1px dashed #999;margin-top: 6px;padding-top: 6px;'>$code[fot]</a></div>";
        }
        $full_content = $foreword.$full_content.$footer;
        if($array['processing'] == 'F'){
            header("Location: show_message.php?msg=2");
        }else{
            if (empty($array['processing'])){ //new schedule
                $sql = "create view sch_$file_id as select id,email,lname,title,count(*) as total from subscriber as s1, subscription as s2, category as c, parent as p where s1.id = s2.user_id and p.cat_id = c.cat_id and s2.cat_id = c.cat_id and parent_id = $parent_id group by id order by total desc;";
                $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                $sql = "insert into schedule (news_id,processing) values ($news_id,'P')";
                $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn); 
            }
            while(file_get_contents("gate.cfg")=="Y"){ //start get subscriber
                $sql = "select * from sch_$file_id as s1 left outer join sentRecord as s2 on s1.id= s2.user_id where news_id is null order by id limit 40";
                $result2 = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                if (mysql_num_rows($result2) != 0) { 
                    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_BOTH)) { //40 different subscribers
                        $body = '';
                        $to = $row2['email'];
                        $headers = "From:Biometrics Alerts <biometrics.alerts@gmail.com>\r\nMIME-Version : 1.0\r\nContent-type : text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nReply-To:biometrics.alerts@gmail.com";
                        if ($row2['title']!='' && $row2['lname'] !=''){
                            $body ="<p style='text-align:right'><a href='http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~bc/preview.php?id=$location&user=$row2[id]' target='_blank'>View this email in your browser</a></p><p>Dear ".ucfirst($row2['title']).". ".ucfirst($row2['lname']).",</p>";
                        }
                        $sentppl = false;
                        if ($row2['total']==12){ //full subscribe
                            $body .= $full_content;
                            $sentppl = true;
                        }else{
                            $body .= $foreword;
                            $sql = "select cat_id from subscription where user_id = $row2[id]";
                            $result3 = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                            while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
                                if($code[$row3['cat_id']] !=''){
                                    $body .= $code[$row3['cat_id']];
                                    $sentppl = true;
                                    $total++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $body .= "$footer<hr/>If you wish to unsubscribe to <a href='http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~bc/' target='_blank'>IEEE Biometrics Compendium Alerts</a>. Please click <a href='http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~bc/unsubscribe.php?user=$row2[id]&cat=$parent_id' target='_blank'>here</a>.";
                        if ($sentppl){
                            /*send code*/
                            if (@mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
                                $sql = "insert into sentRecord values ($news_id,$row2[id],'T')";
                                $result3 = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                            }else{
                                $error = error_get_last();
                                $sql = "insert into sentRecord values ($news_id,$row2[id],'E')";
                                $result3 = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                                $sql = "insert into errorRepord values ($news_id,$row2[id],'$error[message]')";
                                $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                            }
                        }else{
                            $sql = "insert into errorRepord values ($news_id,$row2[id],'Subscriber does not subscribe in that category')";
                            $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                        }
                    }
                    $sql = "select count(*) as total from sch_$file_id as s1 left outer join sentRecord as s2 on s1.id= s2.user_id where news_id is null order by id";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                    $array =  mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    if ($array['total'] < 2900){ //control number
                        file_put_contents("gate.cfg","N");
                        $sql = "drop view sch_$file_id";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn); //delete view
                        $sql = "delete from sentRecord where news_id = $news_id";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn); //sent record
                        $sql = "update schedule set processing = 'F' where news_id = $news_id";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn); //update record
                        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                        $sql = "update schedule set sent_date = '$date' where news_id = $news_id";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn); //update record

                    }
                }
                sleep(3); // set time period
            }
        }
    }else{
        header("Location: show_message.php?msg=1");//newsletter not find
    }
}else{
    // database error
    header("Location: show_message.php?msg=3");
}//end?>
```

Comment: It runs forever because you're never updating `$array['total']`, or is that included in the code you're not showing? Please show all code that is relevant (and the trigger to end the loop is relevant).

Comment: the code is edited. Thank you so much. $array['total'] is the number of email not sent yet