# PHP redirection in between

Tags: php, redirect

I want to do redirect from my login page to the display profile page, but I don't know how to do it. Many suggested the concept of

```
header('Location: $location');
```

but its working only in the beginning part of the code. What if we want to forward it after confirming the username and password?

How about this?

```
echo"<html><?php header('location:www.google.com'); ?></html>";
```

Comment: Try this `header('Location: '.$location);die;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you still have to echo  before your point where you may redirect then I suggest you add **ob_start();** at the beginning of PHP script.

[refers this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504753/how-to-cause-a-redirect-to-occur-before-php-script-finishes)