# php combine redirect and flush

Tags: php, flush, http-redirect

I want a send the response as fast as possible to the user. The response is a redirect to an other page. unfortunately  the script ends with sending the header location. When I use flush first the output is allready sent, so the redirect wont work.

here is a logical example of what i want to achieve:

```
header("location: https://xxxx.xx");
flush();
some_time_consuming_function_with_no_output();
```

is there a way to combine flush and a redirect? any help highly appreciated.

Best endo

Comment: You can try `queue`, like [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues) in laravel.

Comment: _"unfortunately the script ends with sending the header location"_  that is certainly not usually the case

Comment: You can't send output and a redirect like this. As you noted, once you've sent output, you can't send a header. But once you send a redirect header, the browser will go to the new page and ignore any output sent after the header.

Comment: Maybe try a refresh based redirect `header( "Refresh:5; url=https://www.example.com/", true, 303);`  pass in some safe interval like 5 seconds after which it would redirect but again this is subjected to the variable nature of the response so I am not much sure.

Comment: Look here, try the one by Sonia as I know that one works as I have been personally using for many years,.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504753/how-to-cause-a-redirect-to-occur-before-php-script-finishes