# Shell_exec locking browser

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am running PHP on a windows machine in XAMPP environment.
I using an AJAX request to convert a movie from MP4 to OGG

```
function convertMovie(movieName) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'movieManagement.php?queryType=convertMovie&value='+movieName,
       async: true
    });
}
```

and for the PHP code

```
function convertMovie($value) {
    $command = "psexec -d php ".getcwd()."\\movieConverter.php ".$value." > nul 2<&1";
    shell_exec($command);
}
```

and in movie converter the code is something like

```
//some more code here
if ($fileExtension === 'mp4' || $fileExtension === 'MP4') {
            $newFileName = $serverAddress . $tempFileName . "ogg";
            $executeCommand = 'psexec -d '.getcwd() . '\\ffmpeg -i "' . $oldFileName . '" "' . $newFileName . '" > '.$serverAddress.'nul 2>$1';
        }
        shell_exec($executeCommand);
```

Now my problem is every timeI ruin this browser waits for ajax call return like for ever, however, if I run these commands separately in command shell they work fine.
I just want movie conversion to work in background and browser remains free

I know that this question has been asked at least a 1000 times, but I could not find a concrete answer to this. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You can run the process in the background (on Linux anyway) by ending it with `&`:

```
shell_exec($command . ' &');
```

Comment: I wish I could, but I am on windows and I never thought just a simple task as forking a process could be this difficult in this OS

Comment: Windows isn't an Ideal server for most things.

Comment: @AdamSack I would argue it's not an ideal OS for most things (well, at least for development).