# php starting process in background and also waiting for it to finish

Tags: php

I have two scripts (A & B) that a user can call.

If the user calls A, I do a bunch of database access and retrieve a result to return to the user. After I've worked out what I need to send back, I then do a bunch of extra processing and modifying of the database.

I am wondering if it's possible to return the result to the user, and then perform the rest of the processing in some sort of background task.

A further condition would be that if the user that called script A then calls script B, any processing task that user triggered by calling A must be complete, or script B must wait until it completes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Usually it's never a good idea to leave a PHP script to run in background, PHP is not made for this kind of things. Why don't you just wait for script B to be completed before returning results to the user?

Comment: I think the script could take up to 100ms to run in total. If there were a lot of users, it could cause problems. With the background job, I'm guessing it might be able to run during periods of inactivity.

Comment: Nah, don't be afraid of this, really. Your system is already taking care of that. Try to simulate a few thousands requests if you like, but really don't be bothered with that.

Comment: @user1063998 but if you want to *also wait for it to finish*, then it does not matter you ran it as a separate process. the use will still wait the same time.

Comment: Only if the user calls script B immediately afterwards, which is unlikely

Comment: Have a read of these answers, they show how you can run async tasks from php. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php can't perform tasks after closing a request because the request (and the responce sent to browser) are really closed when the php process finish.

Also, php is good for short actions, not long running program like daemons because php lack of a good garbage collector (so it'll eat up all availlable memory before crashing).

What you are looking for is called a queue. When you need to perform some resource (or time) intensive tasks, you put a task into a queue. Then later a worker process will take one item from the queue then perform the task.

This enable you to limit ressource usage by limiting the number of workers to avoid peaks and service failures.

Take a look at resque (for a self hosted solution) or iron.io (for a cloud, setup free solution)

If you are on a shared host (so, no queue and no cron are available) then I recommend you to look at iron.io push queue. That sort of queue will call your server (via HTTP) to send task to it while the queue isn't empty. This way, all the polling/checking queue is done on the iron.io side and you only have to setup a regular page that will perform your task.

Also, if you want the script B to wait for the script A to finish, you'll have to create some sort of locking system. But I'll try to avoid that if I were you because that can cause a deadlock (one thread waiting another, but the other will never finish thus blocking the waiting thread forever)

Comment: PHP has a good inbuilt garbage collector. We have scripts running for months without growing in memory usage.

Comment: If your script does nothing 80% of the time, a cron is useless and will waste power waiting for nothing. Consider using a queue instead that will just pop up when there is something to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

a.php

```
<?php

echo "hi there!";

//in order to run another program in background you have to
//redirect std e err output and use &
//otherwise php will wait for the output
$cmd = "/usr/bin/php ".__DIR__."/b.php";
`$cmd > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &`;

echo "<br>";

echo "finished!";
```

b.php

```
<?php

$f = fopen(__DIR__."/c.txt", "w");

//some long running task
for($i=0; $i<300; $i++){
        fwrite($f, "$i\n");
        sleep(1);
}
fclose($f);
```

Notes:

- Not the most elegant solution but it does the job.
- If you want just one b.php running at time, you can add a pid check.
- The process will run with http user (apache or other) make sure it will have the proper permissions.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are looking for `Ignore_user_abort()`.
This function keeps your script alive for cleanup tasks when the browser has closed the connection.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

You can virtually fork off a browser request by a good combination of `header()`, `set_time_limit()`, `ignore_user_abort()`, `connection_status()`.

It's quite funny in combination with Ajax.

Comment: Down voted because it's a bad solution. If the request is effectively closed and the php process is idle, then the webserver can decide to kill the process without warning. Depending on your OS, killing the parent process will kill the child (forked) process too. This solution isn't reliable enough for a production environement.

Answer (score -1):

to do something like that it's better to use `nodejs`,PHP is synchronized and do its job line by line.(Also you can do develop asynchronous code  in something else like `python` by `asyncore` lib).

But for your question ,you should develop something like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort();
// Working With database
// Echo data to user
ob_end_flush(); 
ob_flush(); 
flush(); 
// Second part of database access,this can be take longer
```

take look at [ob_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) php function,this will not wait to end process ,then render html for user.

Comment: you forgot to close the browser connection at some point, like after the `flush();`

Comment: + every interpreter runs the code line by line + PHP can fork and use signals and threads aswell, no need for python or nodejs, see http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Yeah,but async programming is something different than thread.and php thread is not safe too.
as you know javascript code runs on only one thread and default interpreter of python(CPython) using GLI for threading which is not really thread.

Comment: Threads run async. That's their natural purpose,.. You misplace that nodejs can run non-blocking sockets, like python, but PHP can do that, too. See also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm

Comment: Node.js IO run as other thread,but code is running also in one thread.