# Solution for transcoding server

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, client-server, multitasking

I'm building an transcode server (php-apache), its main job is to transcode media file to general format (ex : mp4). 
Client will upload file to server then wait for reply. 
Server receive the file, transcode to general format then send back http message(link of transcoded-media-file) to client.
The transcode process will execute in the command line.
Is the anyway php can execute the trancoding process, wait for the process complete and return result back the http message to appropriate client (how to know when the process complete) ?

Any one can suggest me a solution, really appreciate !

Comment: Have a look at the [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. It will execute a command line function and return the output as an array.

Comment: @BenFortune exec() return me immediately or wait for the process complete ? Can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

The queuing approach is the best in situations like this.

Here is a good answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/858924/2508830