# how to disconnect the caller but still continue the process

Tags: asterisk

I'm kinda new at asterisk and i have to do a process after hangup, i have a code that is something like this:

```
exten => 12345,1,wait(1)
 same => n,agi(myagi.php)
 same => n,hangup()

exten => h,1,noop("hangup")
 same => n,System(sleep 1m)
 same => n,agi(sendemail.php)
```

so, the call wont hangup when it goes to the h extension because of the sleep, but i need the delay before sending the email, how do i disconnect the caller but still continue the process in the h extension? or is there another way to do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your setup to send the email asynchronously. Basically in your dialplan you will call a shell script that only executes the email script in the background and returns immediately. You'll add the delay into the email script using PHP's `sleep()` function. I've not done this before so don't have any sample code to offer, but [this looks like a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously).

Answer (score 0):

Best way is mark cdr,for example CDR(userfield)=EMAILTO:address.

After that check all cdrs every few seconds/minutes and do action you needed.

Please never use h-extension for task that can take more then 0.5 sec, that can cause issues.