# I can't create a PHP background process

Tags: php, exec, background-process, php-5.6

So basically after a user submits a form I want to create a php background process that checks some stuff with the data they submitted, even if they leave I still want it to be checking but the problem is that I can't get anything to work, I've already looked at all questions related to this on the site and could not find a solution. I did find this code here

```
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, "output.txt", "pid.txt"));
```

but the problem with that is that it only outputs the last thing and it adds some junk in there to.

Output:

```
sh: line 1: *****: command not found
```

Comment: why don't you echo out this and see if it is the command you expect: echo sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, "output.txt", "pid.txt")

Comment: It's not working, it's only echoing the command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run PHP Task Asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously)

Comment: @Mathew it isn't supposed to work. You're supposed to check if the echoed command is correct or not.