# Load web page on server - PHP

Tags: php, exec

I have a web page that contains a php script that pulls data from an API and stores it in a database. My problem is that the script takes 10 minutes to run and stops if the user navigates away from the page on which it's loading - not ideal!

To solve this I'd like to run/load this page on my server as a background job so that a users can still navigate the site without the site or script hanging.

I've had a look at shell_exec but cant seem to make that work:

```
<?php
shell_exec("/usr/bin/php http://example.com/data_base_update.php &");
?>
```

Does anyone know how to trigger a URL on the server, for example http://example.com/data_base_update.php without using a cron job?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Please check out my answer, accept if it serves the pupose.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PHP expert, however your approach for achieving the goal seems bit wrong.

> My recommendation is whenever the URL is hit, start an async task in
>   the background and return the control immediately. Writing async task
>   in PHP does not look simple, however [this theard will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously). You can also use [PThreads](http://www.mullie.eu/parallel-processing-multi-tasking-php/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are opposed to using cron or some kind of automatic task scheduler to handle the long-running process in the background.

I would recommend separating / isolating the long-running task from the code that displays your webpage, move it into a php script that can be called via command line. Then, when a user arrives on your page, you can add the pertinent details to a separate table that would act as a queue.

A cron job could run periodically on your server that would call the php cli script where your API code lives, for each user in the queue table. You could even e-mail notification to the user when the task is complete, or have a button on the page that the user can check if the task is completed yet.

One thing to keep in mind is that if each user requires a 10-minute API call, this could be a VERY long-running script... without knowing the details of the web service you are calling, I would make certain their is no way to submit multiple users in a single call... as this would be a lot more efficient.

Remember, it is important to communicate to the end-user what is happening with dialog / messages like "your information is being gathered and will be available shortly" ... you get the idea.