# Symfony/Silex dispatch events async

Tags: symfony, asynchronous, github, webhooks

I've setup Silex to receive webhooks from, for example, Github. In this case Github sends all the pull requests to a specific Silex API endpoint. According to the Github best practices (https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/best-practices-for-integrators/#favor-asynchronous-work-over-synchronous):

> GitHub expects that integrations respond within 10 seconds of
>   receiving the webhook payload. If your service takes longer than that
>   to complete, then GitHub terminates the connection and the payload is
>   lost.

We should send an answer directly to Github, and process the POST request later.

I've setup my code like this:

```
$app->post('/github/receive/pullreq', function (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) use ($app) {

    $body = $request->request->all();

    $app->after(function() use ($body) {

        $listener = new \Api\Github\Events\PullRequestEvent();

        $dispatcher = new \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->addListener('github.pullrequest.made', array($listener, 'sendTestMail'));
        $dispatcher->dispatch('github.pullrequest.made');

    });

   return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('PR Received', 201);

});
```

And the listener class like this:

```
class PullRequestEvent extends Event
{
    public function sendTestMail()
    {
        sleep(60);

        // the message
        $msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

        // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
        $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

        // send email
        mail("myemail@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);
    }
}
```

I want to send the 201 response to Github first, and then execute the `sendTestMail` function. Is this possible with Silex events? If yes, how should I set this up?

Comment: [Silex application middlewares](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/middlewares.html) are not async

Comment: You can use several approaches for this: [queuing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/858924/5556633), [async http request](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/faq.html#can-guzzle-send-asynchronous-requests) or [backgroud process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously).